# pulling information from MSI files

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I'm working on pulling information from MSI files with Powershell, I have found examples of doing this but they are all value specific E,G if you know the name of the property you can find the value of the property where as I want to find all the properties in the first place, it's actually the information from the shortcut table that I require, example below of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
function Get-MsiDatabaseVersion {
param (
    [IO.FileInfo] $FilePath
)

try {
    $windowsInstaller = New-Object -com WindowsInstaller.Installer

    $database = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "OpenDatabase", "InvokeMethod", $Null, 
            $windowsInstaller, @($FilePath.FullName, 0)
        )

    $q = "SELECT Directory_ FROM Shortcut"
    $View = $database.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "OpenView", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $database, ($q)
        )

    $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null)

    $record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "Fetch", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null
        )

    $productVersion = $record.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "StringData", "GetProperty", $Null, $record, 1
        )

    $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Close", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null)

    return $productVersion

} catch {
    throw "Failed to get MSI file version the error was: {0}." -f $_
}
```

}

Get-MsiDatabaseVersion "C:\Random.msi"

so where $q = "SELECT Directory_ FROM Shortcut" I need to know the names of all the lines in the shortcut table in order to find all the directories. where as at the moment it only returns the first value.
If you can help I'd very much appreciate it.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know the properties of an MSI you can open it in Ocra. I took your code and add a loop to it, please mark the question as correct if it helps you.

```
function Get-MsiDatabaseVersion {
param (
    [IO.FileInfo] $FilePath
)

try {
    $windowsInstaller = New-Object -com WindowsInstaller.Installer

    $database = $windowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "OpenDatabase", "InvokeMethod", $Null, 
            $windowsInstaller, @($FilePath.FullName, 0)
        )

    $q = "SELECT Directory_ FROM Shortcut"
    $View = $database.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "OpenView", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $database, ($q)
        )

    $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null)

    $record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "Fetch", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null
        )

    while($record -ne $null)
    {

        $shortcut = $record.GetType().InvokeMember(
                "StringData", "GetProperty", $Null, $record, 1
            )
        $shortcut

        $record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember(
                "Fetch", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null
            )
    }

    $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Close", "InvokeMethod", $Null, $View, $Null)

    #return $shortcut

} catch {
    throw "Failed to get MSI file version the error was: {0}." -f $_
}
}

Get-MsiDatabaseVersion -FilePath .\Setup1.msi
```

Comment: Thank you very much that's what i needed! and yes I use Orca a lot, the script will eventually be to automate some of the processes I do in it.

Comment: The MSI automation interface was meant for VBScript.  For managed code there are better libraries available.

Comment: You are welcome Ben! I will try the apprach of @ChristopherPainter too.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out:

[Windows Installer PowerShell Module](https://psmsi.codeplex.com/)

The author is a MSFT MSI expert and his cmdlets are far cleaner then doing COM Interop with the WindowsInstaller.Installer object.

```
get-msiproperty Product*, UpgradeCode -path example.msi

get-msitable .\example.msi -query "SELECT ComponentId, FileName, File.Attributes FROM Component, File WHERE Component_ = Component" | where-object { $_.'File.Attributes'.HasVital }
```